# Node.JS will not release localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, localhost

I was building another application in node locally and have now deployed it and am working on another application.

EDIT

However whenever I start node (v5) with express(v4.13) on my localhost it will just hang and not make any connections  I am also on a Mac running El Capitan.  All that I ever see in the console (By Console I mean the Terminal via Logging) is:

```
GET / -- ms --
```

Here is my code below for guidance.

```
var express         = require('express');
var fs              = require('fs');
var logger          = require('morgan');
var cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParer       = require('body-parser');
var path            = require('path');
var app             = express();
var settings        = app.settings;
var env             = process.env;
var entrance        = require('./route/siteBase');

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view cache', false);

app.set('views', __dirname + '/source');
app.set('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/source/assets/'));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

/**
 * 404 Error Handler
 * Creates an error object to be used and passed to pages.
 * TODO move this out of the server.js
 * TODO create generic 500/404 page
 * NOTE this must always be the last route called (i.e. if the server cannot find any other routes this will be called)
 */
 app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  // error page
  res.status(500).render('error', {error : err});
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // logic - TODO: Create Error handling here
  // console.log(req);
  res.status(404).render('error', { error: req.originalUrl });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

module.exports = app;
```

please help!

Comment: can't see where `GET / -- ms --` is coming from ... I'd expect `'Example app listening on port 3000!'`

Comment: I still get that, but when I go to localhost I will see the GET / in my logs.

Comment: oh, that's the message in your browser console?

Comment: No sorry in the Terminal console.

Comment: not from this program it doesn't

Comment: It is coming from this app.  The logger function outputs to terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after a few more hours of debugging the trace led back to some bad NPM package installs which were somehow causing the issue.

I am still not entirely sure what happened, but basically just had to start over from a fresh project and rebuild.

Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The following things you have to keep in your mind.

### install dependencies:

```
$ cd your_app_name && npm install
```

### Install supervisor and use it:

```
npm install supervisor -g
```

### Edit package.json file and replace below lines :

"scripts": {
    "start": "supervisor ./bin/www"
  },

### run the app with debug mode:

```
$ DEBUG=your_app_name:* npm start
```

### run app on different port with debug mode:

```
$ PORT=8080 DEBUG=your_app_name:* npm start
```

### check port is already running or not:

```
$ netstat -anp tcp | grep 3000
$ sudo netstat -lpn |grep :3000
```

### Kill the running port:

```
$ sudo fuser -k 3000/tcp
```

### Convert HTML to Jade: [here](http://html2jade.aaron-powell.com/)

```
http://html2jade.aaron-powell.com/
```

I hope with above information you can sort out your problem.

Answer (score -1):

In express the ordering matters
You have the `hello world` route after the error and 404 handler. 
You need to reorder them.

```
// even better create a routes file and include it here
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404);
  res.send('404: Page not found');
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  res.status(500);
  res.send('500');
});
```

Take a look at a [express-boilerplate](https://github.com/swarajgiri/express-bootstrap/blob/master/bootstrap/app.js#L89) for more details on including routes

Comment: Right I re-ordered and tried it again.  Still same thing.

Comment: Edited the answer, can you  try again

Comment: Sorry tried again still nothing.  Localhost will not load anything.  If I try the app I was previously working on it will launch, but then when I go to this app Localhost just hangs (looks like it is loading but does nothing).

Comment: Are you using any middlewares? If so, make sure you call `next()` at the end of every one of them. If it still does not work, clone the boilerplate linked above and try. If that does not work, it means there is something wrong with your local setup.